# How does int to char array conversion occurs?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

```
void main()
{
     int a;
     char *x;
     x = (char*)&a;
     a = 500;
     x[0] = 2;
     x[1] = 2;
     x[2] = 0;
     cout<<"final op : "<<a;
}
```

I know the answer is 514 . But how does it work ?

Comment: Lookup for integer representation and endianess.

Comment: This is actually very bad behavior here. If the platform default size of "int" is 16 bit (which depends on the target architecture), you'll be writing to memory that you don't own.

Comment: `void main()` is not proper as per `C` standard. Not very sure about `C++`, but I assume it should be simmilar.

Comment: via Undefined behaviour of `x = (char*)&a;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is not standard in C++ as well 3.6.1.2 `a function of () returning int and a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int`

Comment: @RichardCritten: As long as sizeof(int) >= 3, this is Implementation Defined behavior, not Undefined Behavior -- a subtle but important difference.  It is always legal to access any object via a (signed or unsigned) `char` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that exactly how this works is not dictated by the C or C++ standards, and you really shouldn't rely on any specific behavior, unless you *really* know what you're doing and the ramifications thereof. (since you had to ask, you don't fall into that category, even after reading this answer!)

The two most common ways this is done are both that the integer is stored in base 256, storing one digit per byte (bytes are usually 8-bits, and `2^8 = 256`). So when you access it via `char*`, each place represents one digit.

In *little endian* format, you access the digits in order of magnitude; e.g. `x[0]` has the one's place, `x[1]` has the 256's place, `x[2]` has the 256^2's place, and so forth. That is, you access the digits from right to left.

In *big endian* format, the digits are in the opposite order.

Which format is used usually dictated by the computer hardware.

How many base-256 digits make up an `int` can also vary. 4 digits is common, but 2 and 8 happen, and there are even some exotic environments where `int` doesn't fit exactly into this picture at all.

On your particular computer and programming environment, what probably happened was that `int` was at least 4 digits and stored in little endian form; so assigning `500` means the digits were

```
0, 0, 1, 244
```

(because `500 = 244 * 1 + 1 * 256`; remember how to compute change of base!) and then the assignments changed the digits to

```
0, 0, 2, 2
```

which represents `2 * 1 + 2 * 256 = 514`.

(also, note that if `char` is signed in your programming environment, you would probably have read the rightmost digit of `500` as being `-12` rather than `244`: look up two's complement notation)

Answer (score 0):

The way this works is that `x` *points to* the same location that holds the data for `a`.  When you write to or read from `x[0]`, you are accessing the first byte of the value held in `a`. 
This isn't converting between char array and int, this is "accessing an int through a char pointer".

Comment: Yes, I understand , but how does the answer comes exacltly "514". Why is it so.

Comment: @JayantPanwar As I have mentioned that depends on your actual CPU's integer representation and endianess.

Comment: You've basically set a = 0x0202, which is 2*256 + 2 = 512 + 2 = 514.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . Now I get it !